# React Js + Express Route

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Is there a way that i can fetch multiple routes instead of a single one in the code shown here?
i specifically mean this part here - const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/todos",
Is it possible to use await fetch two times?

````
  const [destination, setDestination] = useState("");
  const [start, setStart] = useState("");

    const onSubmitForm = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const body = {destination, start};
            const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/todos", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            });
            
            window.location = "/";

        } catch (err) { 
            console.error(err.message);
        }
    };


  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className="text-center mt-5">Driver Journal.</h1>
      <form className="d-flex mt-5" onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
      <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder= "Start"
          value={start}
          onChange={e => setStart(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Destination"
          value={destination}
          onChange={e => setDestination(e.target.value)}
        />

        <button className="btn btn-success">Add</button>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};


export default InputDrive;```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can create a promise for each fetch request and use Promise.all() to fetch them together.

```
let urls = [
  'https://api.github.com/users/iliakan',
  'https://api.github.com/users/remy',
  'https://api.github.com/users/jeresig'
];

// map every url to the promise of the fetch
let requests = urls.map(url => fetch(url));

// Promise.all waits until all jobs are resolved
Promise.all(requests)
  .then(responses => responses.forEach(
    response => console.log(`${response.url}: ${response}`)
  ));
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mamad this seems promising, I have to try it out when I get back home. Pardon my question but is there a best practice where to put this? What would you recommend?

Comment: @StudioMan It is a best practice to use promises when dealing with async tasks in javascript. Since you want to perform multiple async actions together, Promise.all() sounds appropriate.
Please Vote Up my answer if it helped you.